# JOIN TWO SQL Queries in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for some help combining two queries:

The first:

```
SELECT TITLE, 
       count(TITLE) as DUPLICATES 
FROM CONTENT
WHERE CONTENTTYPE = 'ATTACHMENT' GROUP BY TITLE having count(TITLE) > 1
```

The second is just

```
SELECT CONTENTID,
       TITLE 
FROM CONTENT
```

I wanted to see CONTENTID as part of the first query, but I was not sure how to do that.  The two queries are against the same table, CONTENT.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  If I had to guess, `contentid` is unique and will undo the `group by`.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you want to see all records belonging to a `TITLE` group whose attachment records number in excess of one.  We can try using `COUNT` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TITLE) cnt
    FROM CONTENT
    WHERE CONTENTTYPE = 'ATTACHMENT'
)

SELECT CONTENTID, TITLE
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

This approach uses `COUNT` as an analytic function to identify the `TITLE` records matching your requeiments.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to post (but your explanation and doesn't match the SQL).

Comment: @Larnu Well I typed it out faster.  On the downside, I have carpal tunnel syndrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the rows associated with duplicate attachment titles, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT c.*  -- or whatever columns you want
FROM (SELECT c.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TITLE) as cnt
      FROM CONTENT c
      WHERE CONTENTTYPE = 'ATTACHMENT'
     ) c
WHERE cnt >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT min(CONTENTID) as CONTENTID, TITLE, count(TITLE) as DUPLICATES
FROM CONTENT 
WHERE CONTENTTYPE = 'ATTACHMENT'
GROUP BY TITLE
HAVING count(TITLE) > 1
```

Comment: It is getting bigger and bigger: SELECT CONTENTID,t1.TITLE,t1.PAGEID,COUNT,SPACENAME,CREATIONDATE,LASTMODDATE, VERSION FROM
(SELECT SPACEID,TITLE,PAGEID, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM CONTENT
WHERE CONTENTTYPE = 'ATTACHMENT'
GROUP BY TITLE, PAGEID, SPACEID
HAVING COUNT(TITLE) > 1 AND COUNT(PAGEID) > 1) t1
JOIN
(SELECT CONTENTID,CREATIONDATE,LASTMODDATE,VERSION,TITLE,PAGEID FROM CONTENT WHERE VERSION = 1) t4
ON t4.PAGEID = t1.PAGEID
JOIN
(SELECT SPACEID,SPACENAME FROM SPACES) t2
ON t1.SPACEID = t2.SPACEID 
ORDER BY t1.PAGEID,t1.TITLE, CREATIONDATE, LASTMODDATE